# Move sites to subdirectories without changing base href

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location

I had two staging/test servers hosting each one an angular application on nginx, say app1 and app2. Everything was so simple:

```
http://<ip for app1 server>/   => app1
http://<ip for app2 server>/   => app2
```

Now I would like to host both application on a singleserver. Something like:

```
http://<ip for single server>/app1/   => app1
http://<ip for single server>/app2/   => app2
```

I would like to achieve that without changing the base `href` of my angular application (I know I could do that by changing it with the [--baseHref=... option](https://angular.io/cli/build#options). But as I don't know how my application will be hosted when hitting the production phase, I would like to be `baseHref` agnostic...

So I wrote something maybe to naïve like:

```
location /app1/ {
    root /opt/myapps/;
}
location /app2/ {
    root /opt/myapps/;
}
```

And on the server, I put my sites into both `/opt/myapps/app1` and `/opt/myapps/app2` on the filesystem.

But when I try to open the app1 for example, nothing works as I only get the index.html (from `http://\<ip for single server>/app1/`). The assets don't get loaded because those are taken from the server root and not from the app1 subdirectory (for example `http://\<ip for single server>/favicon.ico` instead of `http://\<ip for single server>/app1/favicon.ico`)

Is that even possible? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the path at which the angular app will be hosted, you could put a relative href in appropriate `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Dashboard</title>
    <!-- relative href -->
    <base href="./" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- Render angular app -->
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that, but great it does the job! Thanks!